# How to auto read json or csv file in postman

Tags: jquery, testing, automation, postman

I saved dynamic access token to json file. when method is ruining i want to assign that json file value to variable in postman. i cant do the file upload manually. because i run postman collection automatically.

i tried that way

```
    jsonData = pm.response.json(); pm.environment.set("token", jsonData.access_token);
    console.log(token);
function readTextFile(file, callback) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
            callback(rawFile.responseText);
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}
    readTextFile("H:\token.json", function(text){
        var data = JSON.parse(text);
        console.log("hhkvhvhkkhf"+data); });
```

Comment: Where are getting `readTextFile()`, Is that a function that you created? How is that token getting saved to that file, is it save as part of a different request?

Comment: sorry now add a full code. I need login to get assess token from API, then i use selenium with java to get access token and access token save to json file. I need read the json file and assign a token to postman variable.

Comment: Are you trying to do all that within the Postman app? Can you not have a separate request in the app that gets and sets the token, then use this elsewhere in the collection. I'm finding it difficult to understand what you're actually doing here.